# Looking for Advanced Single Variable Calculus textbooks (NOT REAL ANALYSIS)

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

Does anyone know any other good advanced calculus textbooks that have much more advanced or rigorous problems?

Textbooks like: Spivak, JEE Main, Advanced Calculus Explored, Problems in Mathematical Analysis (Demidovich), AoPS Calculus, Examples & Problems in Advanced Calculus, Advanced Calculus of a Single Variable, I.A. Maron, etc.

Textbooks that aren't what I'm looking for: Rudin, Apostol, Courant, Folland, G.H. Hardy, etc.

Again, I'm not looking for Real Analysis, I'm looking for like a very "honors" type calculus book without proofs. Please, no proofs, just a calculus book with challenging or advanced problems.

I tried looking through other common Mathexchange questions and they're just proofs and answer the same exact thing that I'm not looking for.

Comment: The majority of olympiads don't do calculus problems, and most undergraduate contests are just proofs or real analysis. But mainly I'm looking for more textbooks that teaches those calculus contest problems and advanced/rigorous kinds of problems like AoPS and "Advanced Calculus Explored" does.

Comment: Spivak is all about proofs, and yet you list him. I taught the AoPS Calculus course a few years ago and found the exercises in that book very uninspired. You should probably take a standard university calculus book (like Edwards & Penney, Rogowski, Stewart, etc.) and find the advanced/challenging problems in them.

Comment: Actually, Spivak has a lot of fun exercises that does not require proofs. Yes there are some chapters and topics that are proofs, but I don't use those sections.

Comment: Why are you so against proofs? Problem solving uses proofs implicitly in the sense that the confidence you have in applying some technique is based on the proof that the technique works and is valid.

Comment: If you just want challenging problems, do visit the tags related to calculus here.

Comment: Some books in the answer to [Joseph Kitchen's Calculus (reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/766183/13130) *might* be what you're interested in. However, their focus is mostly on rigor and proofs, not contest-level formal manipulation (which seems to be what you want), so maybe look in some of the old classics (from the 1800s) listed in my answers to [Extremely “hard” books (or handouts) for undergrad studies](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/3959/745) and [Tables of primitives with indication of solution method](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/14189/745).

Comment: Also, several of my answers give, or cite references to, what one might consider as "contest level" calculus manipulation stuff: [Example 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291496/13130) and [Example 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83100/13130) and [Example 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/62396/13130) and [Example 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58370/13130) and [Example 5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/72126/13130) and [Example 6](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66128/13130) and [Example 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119714/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: and [Example 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137743/13130) and [Example 9](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/429350/13130) and [Example 10](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/383831/13130) and [Example 11](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/777541/13130) and [Example 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767776/13130) and [Example 13](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/739588/13130) and [Example 14](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/735355/13130) and [Example 15](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/715715/13130) and [Example 16](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/712271/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: and [Example 17](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/805871/13130) and [Example 18](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803045/13130) and [Example 19](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2506571/13130) and [Example 20](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681893/13130) and [Example 21](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2999323/13130) and [Example 22](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2810649/13130) and [Example 23](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2780697/13130) and [Example 24](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080921/13130) and [Example 25](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3765876/13130) **(continued)**

Comment: and [Example 26](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3872444/13130) and [Example 27](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1473/745) and [Example 28](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/2172/745) and [Example 29](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1990/745) and [Example 30](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1891/745).

Comment: Oh dang, thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend

1. Irresistible integrals
2. Limits, Series, and Fractional Part Integrals: Problems in Mathematical Analysis(This does have some multivariable stuff but it is challenging book to solve, especially the challenge problems)
3. Inside interesting integrals

Comment: Both Irresistible Integrals(By Victor Moll) and Inside intersting integrals(By Paul J Nahin) Contains many many integrals way beyond single variable calculus syllabus. Both are mostly recommended For Graduate students.

Comment: @user1055 I think inside interesting integrals is reccomended for undergraduates only

Comment: Inside Intersting integrals has somewhat less use of multivariable calculus than Irresistible integrals but still It can't be fully recommended for single variable calculus(As OP asks)

Comment: Still Inside intersting integral has very good single variable calculus problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [MIT calculus book](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/) may fit your needs.

Comment: The book is a bit hard to read, but definitely will be using some of this. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad to help.